# Project template with default custom references, MSBuild tasks and so on: GAX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm looking for creating two Visual Studio 2010, C# projects templates for a client-server platform for which third-party developers can develop their own extensions.

These project templates aren't just code, they need:

- Code generation. The creating of some classes on the fly, and later, easy add some kind of properties with a particular set of attributes.
- Default project references to custom assemblies.
- Custom MSBuild tasks.

As far as I know, because I've been reading some documentation, it seems that **Guidance Automation Toolkit (GAT)** and **Guidance Automation Extensions (GAX)** are the way to go.

But, anyway, I'd like to know if I'm in the right way if I'm thinking in GAT/GAX, or there's some simpler, easier solution to do so.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**: Another point is it seems GAT/GAX is no longer supported. *So, what?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>After some days of research, googling, whatever, I've found there's no official and supported approach by Microsoft to do what I said in my original question.</strike>

In that case, for me the final answer for "*so, what?*" is **who knows**.

Visual Studio SDK is hard to understand, there's documentation on the net, but I believe my extensibility needs would take much time doing *by hand*.

*NOTE* **If someone in the future publishes some interesting answer covering this problem, I'll change my mind.**

**BINGO!**
[Current Microsoft approach is VSPAT/Pattern Tookit Builder!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jezzsa/archive/2012/03/09/10280353.aspx)

This is the official supported approach and it's the GAT/GAX successor.

Comment: @KMoraz No, I've just noticed it exists already and I've installed it in my dev computer. Anyway, since it's a very new product, it's hard to start working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft no longer maintains GAT/GAX. Currently the best successor seems the open source 
[Open GAX/GAT](http://opengax.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I'm unsure that this project will continue its development or not... I'm looking to a good alternative and it should be for the medium/long term.

Comment: I don't think there is a mainstream alternative :|

Comment: I see... So, if you want to create a full project template, with its own references, code generation and so on... GAX/GAT is the only way to go? I mean, "Open" GAX/GAT...?

Comment: That and the existing [GAX](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25e4b5e9-65e4-4950-967d-5f1e6a9dcbeb/?lc=1033) and [GAT](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb473a01-7582-4f25-bde9-cc5b2b9d4cdb/) as long you keep working on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Problem is Visual Studio vNext is just in the corner, and starting now an extensibility based on a 2010-only solution is a bad practices :\

Comment: That's why I've pointed out the open GAX/GAT project, as it supports VS 2012. The code is still by Microsoft, but just not officially supported.

Comment: I don't find OpenGax a reliable project, I don't see community support or strong documentation. So it seems VS extensibility is harder than before.

Comment: Check my own answer. Our answer is Pattern Toolkit.